# r treemap vColor parameter

Tags: r, treemap

I'm using itreemap function from the treemap library.  The parameter I supply for the "vColor" variable seems to be ignored.  My call to itreemap looks like this:

```
itreemap(data3, index=c("organization", "dept", "classnumber", "course"), 
         vSize="enrollment", vColor="score", type="value")
```

However, the interactive treemap always comes up with color set to "enrollment", not "score".  Also, itreemap prints commands on the console.  I think this is so that you can hand tweak the interactive treemap, then get access to the corresponding parameters for later use in code.  When I generate my interactive treemap with the above call, the call itreemap prints on the console is different.  It looks like this:

```
treemap(data3, index=c("organization", "dept", "classnumber", "course"), 
        vSize="enrollment", vColor="enrollment", type="value")
```

As you can see, it ignored my parameter for "vColor".  What could be causing this problem?

Comment: Could you share some of your data to play around?

Comment: activitytype <- c( "label", "forum", "choice", "lesson", "quiz", "workshop" )
score <- c( 72, 6, 77, 750, 273, 36)
enrollment <- c( 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600 )
activitycount <- c(9, 2, 7, 50, 39, 3)
df <- data.frame( activitytype, activitycount, score, enrollment)

itreemap( df, index="activitytype", vSize="enrollment",vColor="score",type="value")

Comment: What's your expected output? Share a picture of the treemap that you would like to obtain

Comment: I can't post an image as I don't have enough reputation points.  My expected output is an interactive treemap with "score" as the initial color variable.  Instead I get an interactive treemap with "activitycount" as the initial color variable.  You can see this by looking at the label for the color scale at the bottom of the treemap display.

Comment: perhaps `treemap( df, index=c("activitytype","score"), vSize="enrollment",vColor="score",type="value")`

Comment: Did this solve the issue?

Comment: That doesn't work.  When I add "score" to the set of index variables, it generates the Error "index variable(s) is(are) not categorical".

Comment: I'll keep trying, but that seems to work when called by `treemap()`, `itreemap()` seems to give out the error that you mentioned. Could be a problem with the package

Comment: My experience exactly.  The treemap() function works as expected, the itreemap() function comes up with the wrong color variable.  It can be switched to use the correct one, but I would prefer not to do that at the start of a presentation.  Any idea what is the best way to get the attention of the package maintainer?

Comment: The [documentation][1] has an email. Package maintainers usually are very keen on fixing bugs and answering to people, I'd try that as a first option

  [1]: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/treemap/treemap.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I contacted Martijn Tennekes, the package maintainer for treemap, and he agreed it is a bug.  Martijn said he will fix it in the next version.